# How to get html code while hitting one website using spring boot and store this whole HTML data in one string variable?

Tags: java, html, spring-boot

I tried to find some stuffs regarding how to get HTML data while hitting any of the website using spring boot but I didn't get any of the best example stuffs.Can anyone help me to give solution for this?

Comment: What you are looking for is called a web crawler, and there are may libraries thatcan do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an HTML parser e.g. `JSoup` to do it.

**Demo:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;

public class JSoupDemo {    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String webPage = "http://www.example.com";
        String html = Jsoup.connect(webPage).get().html();
        System.out.println(html);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head> 
  <title>Example Domain</title> 
  <meta charset="utf-8"> 
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-color: #f0f0f2;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: -apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

    }
    div {
        width: 600px;
        margin: 5em auto;
        padding: 2em;
        background-color: #fdfdff;
        border-radius: 0.5em;
        box-shadow: 2px 3px 7px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.02);
    }
    a:link, a:visited {
        color: #38488f;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    @media (max-width: 700px) {
        div {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: auto;
        }
    }
    </style> 
 </head> 
 <body> 
  <div> 
   <h1>Example Domain</h1> 
   <p>This domain is for use in illustrative examples in documents. You may use this domain in literature without prior coordination or asking for permission.</p> 
   <p><a href="https://www.iana.org/domains/example">More information...</a></p> 
  </div>   
 </body>
</html>
```

**Alternatively,** you can do it using `java.io.BufferedReader` as follows:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(new URL("http://www.example.com").openStream()))) {
            String line;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            }
            System.out.println(sb);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```